Cross origin error in spring boot does not recognize CrossOrigin() annotation
I have Angular in apache2 for frontend and we are using spring boot, in spring boot, I have added @CrossOrigin(origins = “https://frontend.com”) annotation on a controller, and it keeps preventing me from communicating,
`@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = “https://frontend.com”)
public class Department {

    @Autowired
    DepartmentService departmentService;

    @PostMapping(“/input”)
    public ResponseEntity<Message> createDepartment(@Valid @RequestBody DepartmentoDto dto) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(departmentoService.save(dto));
}`

This is the error
Request from another origin blocked: the policy of the same origin prevents reading the remote resource at https://backend/input (reason: missing CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Status code: 403

Object { headers: {...}, status: 0, statusText: Unknown Error, url: https://backend/input, ok: false, name: “HttpErrorResponse”, message: 'Http failure response for https://backend/iput 0 Unknown Error', error: error }

This worked when both were in HTTP, but after switching to HTTPS.
Attempted to test it by allowing all headers, but it did not work:
 @CrossOrigin(origins = “https://frontend.com”,allowedHeaders = “*”)

I think you want that above public ResponseEntity...  right now it's at class level.  It's a handler method annotation.   https and credentialed requests have more strict CORS rules in the browser.

@ cejermador What would be the solution?

try putting "@CrossOrigin(origins = “https://frontend.com”,allowedHeaders = “*”)" futher down in your code... above public ResponseEntity... (it should be at the method that handles the request)

@cejermador still sending the same error

you may want to setup CORS headers globally in Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc-cors.html

The Cors error you are still facing even after you permitted the origin https://frontend.com in your backend application because in the modern days browsers like chrome, edge etc. the same-origin policy is getting checked/validated. That's why you are facing this issue. So, the solution is you need to setup Angular CLI proxy in you angular application to fix this issue. You can refer this link to understand how to configure proxy in your angular application.

the proxy is only used for local debugging.
